# Floating search bar hiding list tiles

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a search floating bar that's supposed to be positioned on top of my ListView
right now this is how it looks like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSqKh.png)

I used this package for the search bar :
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar)

This my the main page :

```
class MyQrqc extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyQrqcPageState createState() => _MyQrqcPageState();
}
class _MyQrqcPageState extends State<MyQrqc> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body:Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,

        children: [

       MyExpanableCardViewFlutter(),
          const SizedBox(height: 50,),
           searchBarUI(),
        ],

      ), //Wrapped into SingleChildScrollView because when click on TextField  keyboard will open and you may get error on screen "bottom overflowed by pixels flutter"
    );
  }
}
```

ListView page :

```
class _MyExpanableCardViewFlutterState
   extends State<MyExpanableCardViewFlutter> {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ListView.builder(
       itemCount: 3,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){

       return Card(
         elevation: 2,
         color: kSecondaryColor,
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
         ),
         child: Container(
           decoration: const BoxDecoration(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
           ),
           foregroundDecoration: const RotatedCornerDecoration(
             color: Colors.orange,
             geometry: BadgeGeometry(width: 32, height: 32, cornerRadius: 16),
             textSpan: TextSpan(
               text: 'Init',
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 10,
                 letterSpacing: 1,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                 color: Colors.white,

               ),
             ),
           ),
           child: ExpansionTile(
             leading: ClipRRect(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
               child: Image.asset(
                 "assets/icons/security.png",
                 height :40,
                 width: 40,),
             ),
             title: const Text("984561225",
               style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 18,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                   color: Colors.black),
             ),
             subtitle: const Text("this should be a title"),
             trailing: Column(
               children: [
                 Expanded(

                     child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                       radius: 20.0,
                       lineWidth: 2.0,
                       percent: 0.8,
                       center:  const Text("80%",
                         style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                       ),
                       progressColor: kPrimaryColor,
                     )
                 ),

               ],
             ),
           children: [
             Row(
               children:  [
                 Expanded(
                     child: Image.asset("assets/icons/user.png",
                       width: 20,
                       height: 20,
                     ),



                 ),
                 const Expanded(
                   child: Text(
                     "Pilot",
                     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                   )



                 ),
                 const SizedBox(width: 50),
                 Expanded(
                   child: Image.asset("assets/icons/product.png",
                     width: 20,
                     height: 20,
                   ),



                 ),
                 const Expanded(
                     child: Text(
                       "product 1",
                       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                     )



                 ),
               ],
             ),
             const SizedBox(height: 10),
             Row(
               children:  [
                 Expanded(
                   child: Image.asset("assets/icons/location.png",
                     width: 20,
                     height: 20,
                   ),



                 ),
                 const Expanded(
                     child: Text(
                       "Perimeter",
                       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),

                     )



                 ),
                 const SizedBox(width: 50),
                 Expanded(
                   child: Image.asset("assets/icons/calendar.png",
                     width: 20,
                     height: 20,
                   ),



                 ),
                 const Expanded(
                     child: Text(
                       "10/02/2022",
                       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                     )



                 ),
               ],
             )

           ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }

   );
 }
}
```

and the Floating search bar widget :

```
Widget searchBarUI(){

  return FloatingSearchBar(
    hint: 'Search.....',
    openAxisAlignment: 0.0,
    openWidth: 600,
    axisAlignment:0.0,
    scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16,bottom: 20),
    elevation: 4.0,
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    onQueryChanged: (query){
      //Your methods will be here
    },

    transitionCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
    debounceDelay: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    actions: [
      FloatingSearchBarAction(
        showIfOpened: false,
        child: CircularButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          onPressed: (){
            print('Places Pressed');
          },),
      ),
      FloatingSearchBarAction.searchToClear(
        showIfClosed: false,
      ),
    ],
    builder: (context, transition){
      return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Container(
            height: 200.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Home'),
                  subtitle: Text('more info here........'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },

  );
}
```

If anyone knows how to solve the issue I'd be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's happening because you put `fit: StackFit.expand,` on your `stack` properity you can change try to change the properties of stack it maybe help the results that you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

or you can also put the `FloatingSearchBar()` within a `Container()` and put the background `color: Colors.transparent` that can help you show the `listTiles` upside down to the `FloatingSearchBar()`. You can try this process if you want.
2ndly, you can also add `sizedbox()` in the `body:` section and before the `listTile()` items to attain the preferred result,
I hope this works, Happy Coding ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can used this way:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  final fsb = FloatingSearchBar.of(context);
  
  return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: fsb.height + fsb.margins.vertical),
      itemCount: 3,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(...);
      }
  );
}
```

Now even the first search result is visible.